# Proper HTTP Error for Deleting Non-empty Resource

Tags: rest, api, http

I use 204 (No Content) to show that the server has fulfilled the delete request of a folder, and 404 for cases where a folder can not be found. I want to issue an error if the DELETE verb is issued for a non-empty folder. What would be the proper HTTP response status code for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the correct one would be 409 Conflict.

```
The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of 
the resource. This code is only allowed in situations where it is expected 
that the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request. 
The response body SHOULD include enough information for the user to recognize 
the source of the conflict. Ideally, the response entity would include enough 
information for the user or user agent to fix the problem; however, that might 
not be possible and is not required.
```

http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html says 409 should be used whenever a resource conflict would be caused by fulfilling the request. Duplicate entries and deleting root objects when cascade-delete is not supported are a couple of examples.

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at the Azure Storage and OpenStack Swift Rest API reference and they both seem to have adopted 409 Conflict for this.